# Comparing NSString in IF statement

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsstring, comparison

As far as I can understand, in order to compare an `NSString`, this is the way to do it:

```
if ([bString isEqualToString:aString]) {
    // Do some stuff here
}
```

How come I get the error messages listed below for the primary `if` statement (but not the secondary statements) when doing just that (as far as I can see)? I understand I am doing something wrong and I have read it over and over but cannot see where the fault is. FYI the hit and miss variables are global int variables.

```
 NSString *hitField = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
        NSString *directionField = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];


    If ([hitField isEqualToString: @"text"]) // Error: "expected ';' after expression" 
    {

        if ([directionField isEqualToString: @"text"]) 
        {
            hitLeft = hitLeft + 1;
        }
}
    else     // Error: "Expected expression"
    {

        if ([directionField isEqualToString: @"text"]) 
        {
            missLeft = missLeft + 1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If ([hitField isEqualToString: @"text"])
```

has a capital I for if - it should be lowercase if.

Comment: Thanks, I read through a dozen of times and still missed it, just goes to show how good it is with a fresh pair of eyes!